# can't install rmr2 for Rhadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, rhadoop

I'm having trouble installing rmr2.

I'm following these instructions: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/user%3Ermr%3EHome

where rmr2 installation is step 4.

I've already installed packages:

```
install.packages(c("rJava", "Rcpp", "RJSONIO", "bitops", "digest", 
                   "functional", "stringr", "plyr", "reshape2", "dplyr", 
                   "R.methodsS3", "caTools", "Hmisc"))
```

And set env. variables:

```
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/Users/virasemenova/Hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/Users/virasemenova/Hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar")
```

And I am now running in terminal:

```
R CMD INSTALL /Users/virasemenova/Desktop/rmr2
and
R CMD INSTALL /Users/virasemenova/Downloads/rmr-3.3.0.tar
```

Each of them return:

- installing to library `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library`
- installing *source* package ‘rmr2’ ...
  ** libs
  sh: make: command not found
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rmr2’

Comment: My guess: You are using a Mac and yoy have not installed Xcode and the command line tools.

Comment: Yeah, Xcode was exactly I needed ! Thanks a lot! (For Mac 10.7.5 I needed Xcode 4.*)